# Twitter app authentication doesn’t follow callback URL despite being provided

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I've provided (what I think is) a valid callback URL, but Twitter refuses to follow it and instead redirects me to an OOB login screen with a PIN. What's going on?

Application settings:
[image]

OOB...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this should only happen if you are providing "oob" as the callback address in request_token. I don't think "oob" is even the default.

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token

> Always send an oauth_callback on this step, regardless of a
>   pre-registered callback.

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based

> The PIN-based flow is implemented in the same exact way as
>   Implementing Sign in with Twitter  and 3-legged Authorization, with
>   the only difference being that the value for oauth_callback must be
>   set to oob during the POST oauth / request_token call.

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm confused. I know it happens if you don't provide a callback url at all as well. I may just be sending the request improperly. [Here's the code I'm using basically stock](https://github.com/bignerdranch/developing-alexa-skills-solutions/tree/master/5_accountLinking/solution/server), if you could take a second to look at it that'd be awesome.